# Как отформатировать столбец даты в DataGridView, чтобы получить "Июль 2016"?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Как в DataGridView настроить отображение столбца с данными типа DataTime, чтобы получить на выходе `"Июль 2016"`? При выполнении программы в русской локализации, конечно.

Понятно, что нужно задать соответствующий формат в `datagridviewcolumn1.DefautCellStyle.Format`. Но какой? Не могу найти описание возможных форматов.
["MSDN Строки настраиваемых форматов даты и времени"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) не подходит. Например, если задать формат `"M"`, то получаем на выходе `"июля 01"`, в то время как в соответствии с вышеприведённой ссылкой, должны были бы получать `"7"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "MMMM" The full name of the month.
>   "yyyy" The year as a four-digit
>   number.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx
Соответственно:

```
DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MMMM yyyy";
```

UPD. Почему `DefaultCellStyle.Format="M"` показывает "июль 01" вместо "7".
По для форматов, описанных одним символом Format пытается смотреть в  [Standard Date and Time Format Strings.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx). А там "M" - это действительно Month/day pattern.
А тот `"M"`, о котором мы оба говорили описывается в  Custom Date and Time Format Strings, и для его использования [нужно писать](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers) `DefaultCellStyle.Format="%M"`

Comment: Вы даёте ту же ссылку, что и я в вопросе. Поясните, почему не работает соответствие, если задать просто "M" ?

Comment: Потому что: `"M" The month, from 1 through 12.` Номер месяца, без лид-нуля. Наименование - MMMM. Год - yyyy. Комбинируя получаем требуемое.

Comment: А, кажется понял в чём вопрос кроме "как получить июль 2016": "получаем на выходе "июля 01"" вместо "7". Покажите код биндинга данных, может там идёт преобразование?

Comment: А если убрать `DefautCellStyle.Format="M"` - выдаётся полная дата?

Comment: да. 01.07.2015 00:00:00

Comment: Этот "M", оказывается, совсем другой "M" :) Обновил ответ.