# Как преобразовать строку к дате

Tags: c#, asp.net

Задача в том сделать расчет даты между текущем временем и датой регистрации юр. лица, если это меньше или равно 3 месяца то выполнять действии
Есть к примеру БИН:`1612300854` здесь первые 4 цифры это год и месяц регистрации
И текущая дата `2016-12-13`
Попытался так сделать:

```
string curDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd");
var b = iinbin.Substring(0, 4);
var s = curDate.Substring(2, 2) + curDate.Substring(5, 2);
var calculation = Convert.ToInt32(s) - Convert.ToInt32(b)
if(calculation >= 0 & calculation <= 3)
{ 
   ///.....
}
```

Но это условие не срабатывает если текущая дата `2017-01-15`,
а у юр лица дата рег декабрь 2016 года(`1612300854`) `1701-1612=89`

Думаю нужно преобразовать строку `1612` или `1701` на дату
А потом почитать кол-во дней и  условие если больше 90 дней

Ожидаю результат : `1612`  --->  `2016-12- 01(любой день)`

Comment: если бы год был указан в виде 4 значного числа то тогда бы можно было делать [так](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xcfzdy4x(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: А 7001 - это январь 1970 года или 2070?

Comment: @Zufir, январь 1970 года

Comment: И граница где будет?

Comment: @Zufir, обновил вопрос

Comment: int z= Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(n / 100, n % 100, 1)).TotalDays);

Comment: только не n, а в данном случае Convert.ToInt32(b) субстракт сам хорошо вытащит количество дней.

Comment: @Bald как вы сделали ссылку так? У меня только так выходит https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx а когда пишу [так][1] то нет [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Обновил ответ, не совсем понял про 90 дней - добавьте сами где нужно..

Comment: @nick_n_a `[текст](ссылка)` - так

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всё элементарно. Парсим дату с помощью `ParseExact`. День по умолчанию будет равняться 1. Далее вычитаем полученную дату из текущей даты. Результат будет в виде `TimeSpan`. Свойство `Days` содержит количество дней в этом периоде.

```
string iinbin = "1612300854";

DateTime regDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
    iinbin.Substring(0, 4), "yyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime curDate = DateTime.Now;

TimeSpan span = curDate - regDate;

Console.WriteLine(span.Days);
```

Answer (score 3):

Вариант 1: получаем год и месяц через деление на 100 и остаток от деления на 100. Формируем новую дату.
Вариант 2: формируем строку и парсим её.

```
    int n = 1612;
    //Вариант 1
    var date = new DateTime(n / 100, n % 100, 1); 
    if (date > DateTime.Now.Date) //Если дата больше текущей - прошлый век.
        date = date.AddYears(-100);
    Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd"));

    //Вариант 2
    DateTime.TryParseExact($"{n}02", "yyMMdd", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
    Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd"));
```

Дальше уже можем сравнивать полученную дату с нужным периодом:

```
if (date.AddDays(90)>DateTime.Now.Date)
{
    //тут Ваша логика.
}
```

Ну и обернуть в try/catch и проверки на случай некорректных входных данных.

Comment: Ссылки на msdn формат даты https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: ненавижу однобуквенные форматы даты. Нечитабельно и легко сделать [ошибку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/541158/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%86-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-datagridview-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%98%D1%8E%D0%BB%D1%8C-2016/541159#541159)

Comment: а зачем дополнительно парсить строку, когда дату уже получили? Или это просто два разных варианта (что вероятнее всего)? разделите их хотя бы пустой строкой чтобы смысл не терялся.

Comment: да, два разных варианта. строка потерялась куда-то

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то сделал бы так

```
    void doWork(DateTime registrationDate)
    {
        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
        currentDate = currentDate.AddMonths(-3);


        if (registrationDate >= currentDate)
        {
            //Do Bussines
        }


    }
```

P.S.: Ну и для полноты, если нужно получить currentDate из BIN по описанным Вами условиям - я бы сделал это так

```
        //БИН:1612300854 
        string strBIN = "1612300854";
        string strYear = strBIN .Substring(0, 2);
        string strMounth = strBIN .Substring(2, 2);

        int year = 2000 + System.Convert.ToInt16(strYear);
        int mounth = System.Convert.ToInt16(strMounth);

        DateTime registrationDate = new DateTime(year, mounth, 1);
```

обернув все в try {} catch()